# FlashBuilder 4.6 - how do setup project for mobile & Desktop publishing?

Tags: ios, flash, apache-flex, air, flash-builder

I have a project created with FlashBuilder 4.6 as "Actionscript Mobile Project" targetting iOS.

I want to be able to compile the same project also for desktop. How can I change the project such that beside the IPA file also a desktop AIR file is created - or how can i switch quickly between the two?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you CAN deploy to desktop from within an Actionscript mobile project, but you only get limited options:

Go to "Export Release Build"->"Export as" select "Signed AIR package for...desktop".

That's it. Just did it and am somewhat happy with it.

Answer (score 1):

I know this will not really answer the question, but actually it does not look possible to do this.

The best way I found to achieve this goal (1 code -> destop + mobile) was to make 2 projects 1 for mobile, 1 for desktop, sharing the same single library full of my app classes + sharing the assets, etc... The only thing that cannot be shared is the descriptor xml file + base class file (though setting up those files is a one-time duty).

A good illustration of how things work can be found on Chris Campbell reversi project page : checkout the last screenshot [in his post right here](http://blogs.adobe.com/cantrell/archives/2010/04/one_application_five_screens.html)

I hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

You can't deploy to both desktop and mobile devices from the same Flash Builder project.

One option is to move your shared code into a library project, and then create one project for mobile devices and one for desktops, each relying on the shared code in your library.

Another option is to compile using the command line tools.

Comment: why is that not possible? seems strange to me considering the fact that there's currently all about 'multi platform development' in the Adobe AIR world...

Comment: I don't know why it isn't possible; that's just the way it is.  Yes, there is a lot of talk about multi-platform deployment.  However, most likely you'll want to do different things on a desktop than you would want to do on a phone, which may be diff than what you'll want to do on a tablet.  In practical sense, one project doesn't necessarily make sense.

Comment: but isn't that exactly what conditional compilation is meant for?

Comment: No; Conditional Compilation is primarily used for app debugging purposes: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7abd.html .

Comment: -1. Just set up a new launch configuration http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashbuilder/using/WSe4e4b720da9dedb5-15a3a08712e93a1ff8e-7fff.html

Comment: @AmyBlankenship I'm not sure if you ever used Flash Builder; but you cannot create a desktop launch configuration for a mobile project [unless you want to launch it in a device emulator].  Launch configurations are also completely unrelated to your ability to create release builds.  Do you believe I have grossly misunderstood the original question?

Comment: I see what you mean. You could probably delete the project and recreate pointing to the same code for your release build. If configuration is difficult, possibly you would want to back up the project properties.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship If he wants to deploy to both iOS and the desktop, I'm not sure what deleting a project would accomplish.  He'll need two separate projects in Flash Builder to do that.  However, he could create two separate projects and make use of a linked source directory to use the same source code.  My preference would be to move shared code into a library, though.

Comment: When you create the new project, you get to say what the default build is, so you could switch back and forth that way (he asked for a quick way to switch back and forth.

I agree about the library. If nothing else, your Views should take the strengths and weaknesses of the device into account.

Comment: There are different project types for Mobile and Web and Desktop apps. So if by selecting "Default build" you mean selecting a project type, then you are correct.  But, I personally don't think that deleting a project and recreating it is quick or efficient, especially when he could create two projects side by side easily.

Comment: So I tried to create two projects side by side and create a source directory shortcut in one of them - but flash-builder doesn't seem to accept folder-shortcuts. at least they do not show up in flashbuilder

Comment: @Mat I'm not sure what you mean by "Folder-shortcut."  I use linked directories, all the time.  From a Flash Builder project, choose File-->New--Folder.  Enter the name of your new folder, then select "Advanced".  Click "link to alternate location [linked folder]" and point it to the location of your source.  Then you'll have to go into the Flash Builder project properties and change your primary source directory to the linked folder.

Comment: great! that works! =) only problem is now that my main-app.xml is within the src folder and i need slightly different settings for my mobile and my desktop deploy. can I somehow have my main-app.xml outside of the src folder so that i can have different ones for the mobile and the desktop project?

Comment: @Mat I don't thyink you can have your main-app.xml outside of your source folder.  You can create two different main application files, though.  That may be your best bet, even if your source code is identical in both.  Then you'll have two separate app descriptor files that you can modify.  Just right click your new main app file and select "set as default application".

Comment: Is there a solution/walkthrough out-of-the-box for quickly compiling a mobile project for desktop through the command line?

Comment: @BillKotsias no shortcut that I'm aware of.  Just look up the Docs on the Flex Compiler. http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7ffd.html